# Why I can't run a Vue project with a problem in app.scss?

Tags: firebase, vue.js

I want to run a Vue project in local. And after I run the command

```
npm run dev
```

It shows me an error like this:

```
 error  in ./src/assets/scss/app.scss

Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/alexchen/Docum
ents/GitHub/demenagement-frontoffice/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
```

What's the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove node modules folder locally and then do `npm install` again. This should do your work